# least privileges required to get ddl of an oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle database and a user that has all privileges to access that database. Now I want to create a new user who can only get the DDL of that database and can only read the data. What are the least privileges or roles that are needed to be granted to the new user?
I don't want to perform any kind of alter, update or delete on that database.

Comment: What do you mean by: *Now I want to create a new user who can __only get the DDL__ of that database*. DDL includes `create` and `alter` statements. And when you say *database*, do you mean *schema*?

Comment: I mean, I want to grant the least permission to user - So that user can get ddl schema for all db objects like Table, Procedure, View, Trigger etc. for CREATE / Update / DROP. As well as Only the permission to fetch the table records of the granted database. [ User must not allowed to execute Delete, Update, Insert query on the database.]

Comment: @sstan - I believe what he/she means is access to read the catalog tables/views (so, for example, the new user can see what tables exist, what columns they have, what constraints, indexes etc.) but no ability to run DDL or DML statements. Something like read-only access, but not limited to the tables within his own schema.

Comment: This question may be better asked on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am not a DBA but I think you need SELECT ANY TABLE and SELECT ANY DICTIONARY